# Are QGIS feature subsets incompatible with table joins?

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

When using QGIS 2.8.2, I am unable join a table to a layer that has a feature subset (Layer Properties > General > Feature Subset).

For example, creating a feature subset on a layer prior to joining an attribute table to that layer always results in no joined records.

Conversely, I cannot create a feature subset on a layer after joining an attribute table to that layer because the feature subset query builder button is greyed out.

Thus, I cannot combine Feature Subsets with table joins.

This appears to be a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so much a bug as something which just wasn't implemented yet. The good news is that this has been implemented in QGIS 2.10, so filtering joined layers will be possible when 2.10 is released.

Comment: I am using QGIS 2.12. While I can filter joined tables, I cannot use one of the joined fields as a variable for the join. Am I missing something? For example i've got Field A and Joined Field B. Now I want to filter the Layer using both fields, but I can't insert Field B in my query...